# What is the right way to dispose a WebView page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, webview, xamarin.forms

### The problem

I have an app in Xamarin.Forms that opens a WebView after a login screen.

Each time the user logs out and in again, a new Page and ViewModel are created.

Inpecting the device via Chrome's Remote Devices I can still see the older WebViews.

For the navigation I use a custom NavigationService inpired by the Evolve App from a couple of years ago.

### What I've tried so far

Disposing both the Page and it's ViewModel when poping the WebViews's Page.

This is the code that pops the WebView's Page and return to the Login Page

public async Task NavigateBackAsync(bool IgnoraNavegacao)
{
    _isNavigating = true;

```
try
{
    /* Omitted for clarity */

    if (currentPage is IDisposable)
        ((IDisposable)currentPage).Dispose();

    if (!(currentPage.GetType() == _homeViewModel))
    {
        await navigationPage.PopAsync();
    }
}
finally
{
    _isNavigating = false;
}
```

The **Dispose** of the Page, where Browser is my WebView defined in XAML:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        Browser = null;

        var bindingContext = BindingContext as IDisposable;
        bindingContext?.Dispose();

        BindingContext = null;
    }
}
```

And this is the **Dispose** of the ViewModel:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        OnNavigatingCommand = null;
        OnNavigatedCommand = null;
        OnBackButtonPressedCommand = null;
    }
}
```

And this is what I see on Chrome after logging in four times:

[image: Chrome Remote Device]

Interestingly enough the first time it "works": after I log out and log in again only one WebView is seen on Chrome.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First works means that login and out successly?And the last three not successly log in and out.Only a webview seen is the server adress?When leaving the webview if send an exit request operation to server.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT All loggins and logouts are successfull. 'First time works' means the first time I log in and out again only one Webview is displayd on Chrome.

Comment: If first webview already shown, you can try `webView.Reload();` next times.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT As the result of the process of navigating to the WebView's page a new Page and ViewModel are instatiated, so I'm not reusing the instance of the WebView. Hence the question: how do I get rid of the old ones?

Comment: Ok,I provide an answer,you can refer it.

Comment: @JeffersonRocha did you find the solution for it?

Comment: @ac-lap I honestly do not remember, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When second to this page.If you didn't create a webview using the singleton mode, then you won't get the previous webview.

So there are two options：

**One：**

Using the singleton mode,when next to this page,you can get the old webview.

**Two:**

When leaving the page, you can set the old instance of the WebView to be `null`.

In `OnDisappearing` method:

```
 protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        if (null != webView)
        {
            webView = null;
        }
    }
```

Or before `Navigation.PopAsync()` do it.